# Guessing game doesn't function properly. Bug that I can't find

Tags: java, debugging, random

So I created a guessing game where the user has three guesses and has to guess the random generated number. I think I have it all under control, but there is a bug that I can't find and fix it. When the user guess the correct number, it should say "You won!", but my program doesn't do that. Need help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class guess {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner firstG = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner secondG = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner thirdG = new Scanner(System.in);

int randomN = (int)(Math.random() * 10) +1;


System.out.println("I'm thinking of an integer in the range 1 to 10. You have three guess.");
System.out.println();

System.out.print("Enter your first guess: ");
  int guess1 = firstG.nextInt();

  if(guess1 > randomN) {
      System.out.println("Too high!");
      if(guess1 > randomN) {
          System.out.println();
          System.out.print("Enter your second guess: ");
          int guess2 = secondG.nextInt();
          if (guess2 > randomN) {
              System.out.println("Too high!");
              if (guess2 > randomN) {
                  System.out.println();
                  System.out.print("Enter your third guess: ");
                  int guess3 = thirdG.nextInt();
                  if (guess3 > randomN) {
                      System.out.println("Too high!");
                      System.out.println();
                      System.out.println("You lose. The was " + randomN);
                      if(guess1 == randomN) {
                          System.out.println("You win!");
                          if(guess2 == randomN) {
                              System.out.println("You win!");
                              if(guess3 == randomN) {
                                  System.out.println("You win!");
                              }
                          }
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

       if(guess1 < randomN) {
       System.out.println("Toolow!");
       if(guess1 < randomN) {
           System.out.println();
           System.out.print("Enter your second guess: ");
           int guess2 = secondG.nextInt();
           if(guess2 < randomN) {
               System.out.println("Too low!");
               if (guess2 < randomN) {
                   System.out.println();
                   System.out.print("Enter your third guess: ");
                   int guess3 = thirdG.nextInt();
                   if(guess3 < randomN) {
                       System.out.println("Too low");
                       System.out.println();
                       System.out.println("You lose. The number was " + randomN);
                       if(guess1 == randomN) {
                           System.out.println("You win!");
                           if(guess2 == randomN) {
                               System.out.println("You win!");
                               if(guess3 == randomN) {
                               }
                            }
                         }
                      }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a bunch of issues in your code.

First you don't need three scanners

```
Scanner firstG = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner secondG = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner thirdG = new Scanner(System.in);
```

You just need one. This is probably why you don't the correct output.

You need to debug your program, from the code you have provided I will assume that you are really new to this, so here's a nice article on how to debug a Java program using eclipse IDE. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Also your if conditions are too screwed up and totally unnecessary, try to see how you can simplify them. A good idea will be to just get a notebook and see how you will handle those same if conditions in real life. You will see that more than half of what you've pasted here is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You should write this as a loop.

But your actual problem is that the `if(guess1 == randomN)` statement is *inside* the `if(guess1 > randomN)` statement.

`guess1` cannot be both `>` and `==` to `randomN` at the same time, so the inner `if` statements will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

to me it seems like it should look this way

```
Scanner guess=new scanner(System.in);
int randomN = (int)(Math.random() * 10) +1;
for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
 {
   int userNum=guess.nextInt();
   if(userNum>randomN)
        System.out.println("Too high!");
   else if(userNum<randomN)
           System.out.println("Too low!");
   else if(userNum==randomN)
   {
           System.out.println("You Win!");
           break;
    }
  }
```